# Connected my ps4 controller to a ps3 now can't connect it back

Tags: ps4, controllers

I need help. Since one of my favorite games was BO2 on ps3 I wanted to play IT again, so I unpackaged my ps3 and connected it to my ps4 controller. But when I was done and wanted to connect it back the ps4 controller wouldn't sync to the ps4, I've tried so many different solutions for about 4 days now and I really wanna play some Fortnite, so can somebody make my week and help me fix it? It's highly appreciated.

I've tried via Bluetooth, tried the turn your ps4 for 3-4 minutes and then try to turn it on, I can't do it via USB port because it won't charge a ps4 controller

Comment: I still haven't solved this problem. Still looking for help

Comment: Have you tried resetting the control?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a similar question here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280286/ps4-controller-not-pairing-with-system/338000#338000

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen to me. I could not pair my controller to my PS4 because it has a bad micro usb port. You need a second DS4 paired to the PS4, or some kind of input device to do this.

-put unpaired controller into pairing mode by pressing the PS button and Share button at the same time. The light bar will start flashing.

-navigate to Bluetooth menu

-select "Add device"

-select "wireless controller"

-select pair

There may be an extra step somewhere in here depending on what version your PS4 is on.

Comment: I've already tried the Bluetooth option, but the controller wouldn't show in the Bluetooth devices menu, after multiple tries.